# Add a delay between AWS instance creation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation create-stack command to create instances. The template uses `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` as a scaling group. Is it possible to add a delay between instance creation?

Looked through the documentation but could not find anything useful.

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to introduce the delay. If you provide information about what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to recommend an alternative way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is **no such functionality available when creating the ASG**. Thus, if you define your ASG with  `DesiredCapacity` of, for example, 3, all the instances will be created at the same time.

However, it is worth noting, that although you can't define a delay time on the initial ASG creation, you can specify the delay during performing **rolling updates** of your ASG later. In this case you define [AutoScalingRollingUpdate Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html#cfn-attributes-updatepolicy-rollingupdate) for the ASG. The policy has a parameter `PauseTime` which is:

> The amount of time that **AWS CloudFormation pauses** after making a change to a batch of instances to give those instances time to start software applications.

Also, it should be mentioned that  `PauseTime` works this way when `WaitOnResourceSignals` is `false`.